# Dereferencing void pointer to assign value to struct

Tags: c++, pointers

I have several structs containing various combinations of parameters. I wrote a function that takes a void pointer reference to the structs (there are several different types), and writes information from the data parameter into them. Here's the function below:

```
void SubModelBase::writeDataStruct(byte msgID, void *ptr, QByteArray data)
{
    *(byte*)ptr[0] = msgID;
    *(byte*)ptr[1] = data.length();

    for (int i = 2; i < data.length(); i++)
    {
        *(byte*)ptr[i] = data.at(i);
    }
}
```

The void *ptr is the reference to the struct that I want to write the data into but I'm having issues deferencing the pointer so I can write into it. I'm sure I'm just missing something silly in my syntax here but I'm not seeing it at the moment...

**EDIT:**

Ok, I rewrote the function to first cast the void pointer to a byte pointer before assigning values:

```
void SubModelBase::writeDataStruct(byte msgID, void *ptr, QByteArray data)
{
    byte* structData = (byte*)ptr;
    structData[0] = msgID;
    structData[1] = data.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
    {
        structData[i + 2] = data.at(i);
    }
}
```

Not tested yet but now it at least compiles. I did it this way because there are over 30-40 different structs that need to have data filled in them and I needed a single function that can handle the operation easily without knowing the details of each struct. However, if there is a better way to approach the problem, I'm definitely open to ideas.

**EDIT 2:** Fixed logic error in loop

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to write to a struct via a projection to a byte array. I would recommend to cast `ptr` to a pointer to a particular struct based on some dispatching parameter (`msgID`?).

Comment: You can not dereference void pointers. You must cast them to their actual type first. Is this meant to be something like `memcpy`?

Comment: You can't write into a struct through a `byte*`. You need to cast to the appropriate type. (It's not just some silly syntax you're missing, it's something important and fundamental about semantics and types.)

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica Assuming `ptr` was never actually declared as the specific struct type (e.g. say its a `char buffer[256]` or some other struct like a `DataPacket`) doesn't that risk problems with alignment, aliasing, etc.?

Comment: What actually is the struct type here, what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to take some struct, convert it to bytes for file/network IO, then convert it back again safely? Why do you skip `data.at(0)` and `data.at(1)`?

Comment: Yes, the structs are basically data stores for serial data that is being written to/from a hardware device. So I am serializing the data from the structs as a byte array for transmission and then reading it back from the received serial data and populating the structs.

Comment: If they have a common layout, may I ask why you did not simply made the common part to be a base structure from which the others are derived? And then simply having a pointer to the base structure as argument?

Comment: Can it be a `union` of `struct` and `byte array`. push the data in `union.struct.member` and use `union.byteArray` for seraialization

Comment: Some of the structs are actually unions of intividual bytes and bits of data. I didn't design the structs, but I'm just writing the code to interface with them. @FireLancer, the first two bytes of the struct contain parameters that are not in the data array I'm passing in, so I have to directly set the first two values.

Comment: But your not setting `data`, your reading from it and just skipping two elements? If they are not in the array, shouldn't it be `i = 0; ... structData[i + 2] = data.at(i)`?

Comment: @FireLancer YES, you're right, my mistake! Thanks for catching that :-). Above code has been updated

Comment: This site uses a Question/Answer format -- instead of editing the answer into the question, post the answer in the Answer box

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for is a template so the compiler creates the correct method when you need it.